# Best practices in exposing interface

Tags: c#, code-quality, coding-standards

Let's assume I have a class that downloads data from API, cleans it and saves to database. What methods should I expose?

```
class ApiConnector1
{
    public string GetDataFromApi()
    {
        // ...
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// removes unnecessary records
    /// </summary>
    public string CleanApiData(string apiData)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public bool SaveToDb(string processedData)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class ApiConnector2
{
    public string GetDataFromApi()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public bool SaveData(string processedData)
    {
        SaveToDb(CleanApiData(processedData));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// removes unnecessary records
    /// </summary>
    private string CleanApiData(string apiData)
    {
        // ...
    }

    private bool SaveToDb(string processedData)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class ApiConnector3
{
    public bool GetDataToDb()
    {
        SaveToDb(CleanApiData(GetDataFromApi()));
    }

    private string GetDataFromApi()
    {
    }
    private string CleanApiData(string apiData)
    {
    }
    private bool SaveToDb(string processedData)
    {
    }
}
```

and usage

```
// ApiConnector1 usage
var apiConnector = new ApiConnector1();
var apiData = apiConnector.GetDataFromApi();
// show information that data was successfull downloaded
var cleanData = apiConnector.CleanApiData(apiData);
apiConnector.SaveToDb(cleanData);


// ApiConnector2 usage
var apiConnector2 = new ApiConnector2();
var apiData2 = apiConnector2.GetDataFromApi();
// show information that data was successfull downloaded
apiConnector2.SaveData(apiData2);


// ApiConnector3 usage
var apiConnector3 = new ApiConnector3();
apiConnector3.GetDataToDb();
```

My thoughts:
In Approach 1 when somebody want to use class he have to call method in proper order, which can create bugs if he not. On the other hand in approach 3 is easy to use but introduces little magic (he doesn't know what will happen), and is hard to unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case #1 and #2 are **not** easy to unit test, they are in fact *more* difficult to *properly* unit test. They have lots of invalid call sequences that you have to specify the behavior of.

Case #3 is simplest to both use and test; this is generally true because tests should mirror usage. Greater complexity of usage is almost always going to mean greater complexity of testing. #1 or #2 should only be used if there is a use case where the individual steps are necessary (e.g load data but don't save to db).

Even then you can probably do better by setting up a [fluent api](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) so that invalid call sequences are inherently impossible, something like:

```
api.loadDataSet().clean().saveToDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless is makes sense to call these operations separately then option 3 should be used.

If these operations should only be called in a specific order then they should be grouped into a single cohesive interface.

I would only look at splitting these up if they were useful individually or perhaps option 3 resulted in many hidden side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You should not open any business logic method to outer class.

```
class ApiConnector
{
    private string GetDataFromApi()
    {
        //Logic
    }
    private void CleanApiData(string apiData)
    {
        //Logic
    }
    private void SaveToDb(string processedData)
    {
        //Logic
    }

    public GetDataAndSeaveToDB()
    {
       var appdata=null;

       appdata = GetDataFromApi();

       //validateData received data

       CleanApiData(appdata);
       SaveToDb(appdata);
    }
}


var apiConnectorObj = new ApiConnector();
apiConnectorObj.GetDataAndSeaveToDB();
```